# Managing privacy within a large program

Tags: java, package, privacy, factories

I'm working on a program for robotics with this structure *(I'll include what the layers do just for laughs)*:

- **Layer A - GUI** simple interface to handle buttons, joysticks, etc. Translates these values into commands to send to the control interface.
- **Layer B - Control** evaluates device-read/write-entries from the database and command requests from gui, in order to calculate new device-write-entries for the database
- **Layer C - Database** logical representation of devices, creating a history of values written and read from the devices
- **Layer D - Hardware** talks to physical hardware. Translates device-write-entries into commands and sends them to the devices. Updates the database device-read-entries with values from the devices.

I want to create a java application where no layer is able to call functions which are more than one layer above or below it.

Is it possible to create a project structure using package privacy, or patterns like factories which makes it impossible for code in, lets say Layer A, to import anything from Layers D or C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something that you can achieve using access modifiers alone.

You also can't do it by (somehow) controlling `import` ... because the Java language doesn't place any (extra) restrictions on imports.  (The `import` directive is really just syntactic sugar so that you don't need to use fully-qualified names everywhere.)

So what else could you do?

- You could try to implement runtime restrictions to prevent the wrong layer getting access to factory objects.  But such restrictions are easily subverted, deliberately or by accident.
- You could use some kind of internal "capability" or "credential" mechanism, but it is hard to see how you would prevent credential leakage. (If the credentials were managed by a security manager (see below) that might work, but that's making the problem more complicated.)

The only way I think you could do it would be to implement a custom `SecurityManager`, and implement security checks each time there is a potentially layer-crossing call.  For example, it is possible (though expensive) for a security manager to check the call stack to find what method / class / package called it.  You would also need to turn off certain reflective operations that can be used to (trivially) subvert the security manager.  Essentially, all but the inner ring needs to be treated as "untrusted" code.

Frankly, implementing this kind of thing with a JVM with "hacker-proof" security is probably beyond the capability of a mortal human.  (Sun / Oracle haven't succeeded yet ....)

---

The other alternatives are:

- Rely on programmer discipline.
- Rely on static analysis of the codebase; e.g. aided by annotations that document the access rules.  You would need to write your own code analyser to do this.
- Use address-space separation, and small footprint, security-minded APIs between the layers.  (We are no longer talking about a single conventional JVM here ...)

Comment: Just asked the same question to Michael Aaron Safyan, but in your opinion are these expensive/ involved approaches realistic for the sake code maintenance? or is programmer discipline the way to go?

Comment: Programmer discipline is sufficient if you are only concerned about code maintainability.  IMO.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR there is no one magic bullet solution to this, but many different tools to leverage

There are a variety of different techniques to isolate different parts of a software application, but I don't think there is any one solution that solves everything. Some build systems can restrict dependencies between targets (e.g. [Bazel](http://bazel.io/) has a `visibility` property on build targets that can prevent one target from depending on another target, even if they are visible to each other via Java's class visibility) which can be used in conjunction with Java's builtin visibility. For example:

```
 // Foo.java
 package com.yourcompany.foo;
 public class Foo {}

 // Build rule for Foo.java
 java_library(
    name = "Foo",
    srcs = ["Foo.java"],
    # Restricts visibility to this directory, even though
    # the class visibility was "public" 
    visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
 )

 // Bar.java
 package com.yourcompany.bar;

 import com.yourcompany.foo.Bar; // prevented by build visibility system

 public class Bar {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
 }
```

It is also possible to use interfaces to mediate all interactions between logical components and to hide the implementations of those interfaces (e.g. exposing the implementation only through a service registry interface or through interface dependency injection). For example, with [Dagger](http://google.github.io/dagger/), you could create a separate [component](http://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.0/dagger/Component.html) for each layer, which would allow you to write code like:

```
final class ControllerImpl implements Controller {
   // Since "ControllerImpl" is instantiated / wired into the
   // controller layer, the database dependency is available /
   // exposed for injection within this layer. The access control is
   // strictly performed by the way the dependencies are wired.
   @Inject
   public ControllerImpl(Database database) {
     // ...
   }
}
```

In addition to the above, you can use dependency analysis / dependency analysis tests or commit hooks to automate detection of dependency rule violations (and trigger errors / reject submissions based on them). For example, a poor man's solution would be to simply scan each file for its package declaration and its import statements, and then have some heuristic to detect a bad dependency.

Another approach is to bundle different components in separate JARs and load them with a custom [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html), which would allow you to prevent illegal accesses using reflection (which could otherwise circumvent any program structure).

In addition to automated methods, manual approaches also have their value. Manual approaches include regular code reviews and policies to be enforced during those code reviews and auditing.

In short, there is no one right answer. It's necessary to use several different approaches in conjunction, depending on how critical this separation is.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize how big a question this would actually be! The idea of restricting layer access was to make sure code was maintainable. Would any of these solutions be advisable for a extracurricular project, which will probably only last a year or two tops? Or would as Stephen C said, "Rely on programmer discipline" be a more appropriate approach?

Comment: Ok. If it's just about neatness and not a strict privacy concern here, then mediating control through interfaces, using an injection framework to manage dependencies, and manual discipline should be more than sufficient, especially if the code base is of a reasonable / manageable size. If you haven't selected a build system yet, though, I would recommend Bazel (I'm a bit biased, though) and, if you are using it, you might as well leverage its visibility restrictions. But if you already have a different build system in mind, then that sort of thing isn't needed.

Comment: IMO, they would not be advisable for a "small" project.  But if your aim is to build something that has a hope of turning into a viable production ready platform with real security, you have no choice but to come up with a production quality solution.  Don't think people haven't already tried ... and (objectively) failed.  This is a seriously difficult problem.

Comment: Right, this doesn't make sense for something small... for something small, do it in the hackiest way possible that gets you to minimum viable product. But it sounds like this project encompasses several layers of a robotics system, and if you hope for this to get to a production / commercial grade level, then some elements are necessary. (The elements I'm recommending to use in your project are advisable in the medium-large category, and all of them are advisable on the large-ginormous range where some subcomponents handle sensitive data).

Comment: That sounds like a project where strict layering is not strictly necessary.  In fact, strict (strictly enforced) layering sounds tangential to the problem you are really trying to solve.  Put it on one side, and focus of the real problem.

Comment: @StephenC agreed, which is why in my comment, I've indicated that only some pieces are needed to be "neat" and the other pieces (like custom class loaders, automated dependency analysis, etc.) for stricter enforcement are not necessary.

Comment: @StephenC and Michael Aaron Safyan, Thank you very much for the advice! I'll have to take some time this week and look deeper into these concepts :)